# NetBeans "final method is declared in class with normal scope"

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

NetBeans complains that "final method is declared in class with normal scope", this method is called from constructor so I declared it final to avoid being issued a "Overridable method call in constructor".

What's wrong with a final public method in a class?

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class A implements Serializable
{
    boolean initialized;
    public A()
    {
        setInitialized(true);
    }

    public final void setInitialized(boolean b)
    {
        this.initialized = b;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: the complaint from the compiler is differently phrased but states the same:

```
Normal scoped bean class A is not proxyable because the type is final or 
it contains a final method public final void A.setInitialized(boolean) - 
Managed Bean [class test.so.A] with qualifiers [@Default @Any @Named].
```

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: please give us your code.

Comment: I think [this reference](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.1.0.Final/en-US/html_single/#d0e1429) explains why you shouldn't do this (you cannot make a proxy that overrides the behavior of your final method).

Comment: yes I think it's clear now, I mostly did this question so that search engines can quickly pick it up when it happens next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Netbeans Wiki reference](http://wiki.netbeans.org/CDIFeatures71) should clear your doubt:

> **Warnings**
>
> Classes with normal scope which have final methods ( it doesn't apply
>   to classes without any CDI annotation and without explicitly defined
>   scopes, f.e. default @Dependent scope is pseudo-scope not normal. )
>   This is warning because only "bean type methods" should not be final (
>   i.e. methods which declared by bean type of injection point ).

Comment: I might be the only one, but I don't understand a word of this warning. Can you state in your own words why this should be avoided?

Comment: You're not the only one. Specifically which part of the JLS does the OP's construct contravene?

Comment: I can't understand the above clearly, "This is warning because only "bean type methods" should not be final ( i.e. methods which declared by bean type of injection point )." sounds badly phrased to me.